# C - Trying to make an array of LinkedList pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to create a `HashTable` in C where each 'bucket' is a pointer to a `LinkedList`. That is, I need to create an array of `LinkedList` pointers.

As of now, `SomeHashTable->Buckets[i]` is returning a non-pointer `LinkedList`. I've been looking for answers everywhere and I just can't find anything. Perhaps I'm overlooking something? I've given my current code below.

**HashTable.h**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"

typedef struct HashTable
{
  LinkedList* Buckets[1009];
} HashTable;

//Creates new hashtable
HashTable* HashTable_new();

//Hashes and adds a new entry
void HashTable_add(HashTable* Table, int data);
```

**HashTable.c**

```
#include "HashTable.h"
HashTable* HashTable_new()
{
  HashTable* newTable = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
  newTable->Buckets = malloc(1009 * sizeof(LinkedList*));

  //Create linked lists
  for (int i = 0; i < 1009; i++)
  {
    newTable->Buckets[i] = LinkedList_new();
  }

  return newTable;
}

void HashTable_add(HashTable* Table, int data)
{
  int index = data % 1009;

  //Get bucket to hash to
  LinkedList* BucketHead = (Table->Buckets[index]);
  //Hash it iiinnnn real good
  LinkedList_add_at_end(BucketHead, data);
}
```

The linked List structs for reference:

```
typedef struct LinkedListNode {
    int data;
    struct LinkedListNode *next;
    struct LinkedListNode *prev;
} LinkedListNode;

typedef struct LinkedList {
    struct LinkedListNode *first;
    struct LinkedListNode *last;
} LinkedList;
```

Comment: Why are you allocating memory to `Buckets` --> `newTable->Buckets = malloc(1009 * sizeof(LinkedList*));`? `Buckets` is already an array of `1009` elements of type `LinkedList*`.

Comment: A good read [Eternally Confuzzled - Hash Tables](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/datastructures/jsw_tut_hashtable.aspx). Well worth a read. Another from Yale [C/HashTables](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/C(2f)HashTables.html?highlight=%28CategoryAlgorithmNotes%29) Both helpful. Favorite [Coding a Hash Table](http://www.sparknotes.com/cs/searching/hashtables/section3.rhtml)

Comment: Also, unless you have some unexplained purpose for using a *doubly-linked list* of buckets, it's generally a one-way-street (e.g. a *singly-linked* implementation) You do not benefit from double-linking in either initial filling or in re-hashing to keep your *load factor* below your target (generally `.7` is OK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As H.S.'s comment mentions, there is no need to dynamically --and-- statically allocate the Buckets array.

This line:

```
newTable->Buckets = malloc(1009 * sizeof(LinkedList*));
```

is overwriting the pointer to the statically allocated array, which is probably not what you want. For scalability, I would ditch the static array and stick with malloc(). That way you could use an argument to HashTable_new() to specify the size of the buckets array, like so:

```
HashTable* HashTable_new(int nBuckets)
{
  HashTable* newTable = (HashTable*)malloc(sizeof(HashTable));
  newTable->Buckets = malloc(nBuckets * sizeof(LinkedList*)); 
  newTable->nBuckets = nBuckets;

  //Create linked lists
  for (int i = 0; i < nBuckets; i++)
  {
    newTable->Buckets[i] = LinkedList_new();
  }

  return newTable;
}
```

Notice that newTable->Buckets is being allocated as a pointer to a pointer to  LinkedList (LinkedList**). You'll need to keep track to the size of Buckets[], so add the variable to the struct as follows:

```
typedef struct HashTable
{
  int nBuckets;
  LinkedList **Buckets;
} HashTable;
```

You should be good as long as LinkedList_new()'s return type is LinkedList*, and don't forget to free() it all when you're done.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to work now. I'm wondering why you malloc'd nBuckets * LL** as apposed to a LL*. Shouldn't the buckets just be pointers to linked lists? Not double pointers?

Comment: You're totally right. I've edited the answer to reflect that. Note that since malloc() returns void* and a pointer is usually the same size as a double pointer, there is no functional difference, so it would work either way.